# template parameters not deducible in partial specialisation

Tags: c++

Why does the following not compile?

Does it have something to do with dependent types?

```
template<typename T>
using element_type_t = std::remove_reference_t<decltype(*std::begin(std::declval<T&>()))>;

template<typename T>
struct is_json_allowed : std::false_type {};

template<typename T>
struct is_json_allowed<typename std::enable_if_t<
    !std::is_array_v<T> && !std::is_class_v<T> && (
    std::is_void_v<T> ||
    std::is_same_v<T,int> ||
    std::is_same_v<T,unsigned int> ||
    std::is_same_v<T,std::string> ||
    std::is_same_v<T,bool> ||
    std::is_same_v<T,float> )
,T>> : std::true_type {};

template<typename T>
struct is_json_allowed<std::enable_if_t<
    std::is_array_v<T> && is_json_allowed<element_type_t<T>>
,T>> : std::true_type {};

template<typename T>
inline constexpr bool is_json_allowed_v = is_json_allowed<T>::value;

class Node
{
public:

    template<typename T>
    std::enable_if_t<is_json_allowed_v<T>,Node&> operator=(const T& rhs)
    {
        m_type = typeid(T);
        m_data.resize(sizeof(T));
        std::memcpy(&m_data[0],&rhs,sizeof(T));
    }

private:
    std::type_index m_type;
    std::vector<unsigned char> m_data;
};
```

Error is:

```
||=== Build: Debug in JSON (compiler: Mingw-7.3.0) ===|
json.hpp|21|error: template parameters not deducible in partial specialization:|
json.hpp|21|note:         'T'|
json.hpp|32|error: parse error in template argument list|
json.hpp|32|error: template parameters not deducible in partial specialization:|
json.hpp|32|note:         'T'|
||=== Build failed: 3 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

I have tried throwing a bunch of `typename`s in there, but I clearly don't know what I'm doing. The goal of the above is to limit the types that can be assigned to a `Node` to being JSON-ish types.

I didn't want to have to write a bunch of individual specialisations for the assignment and other future operators.

Comment: Can you show how you use the assignment operator?

Comment: I'm not using it at all, just including the above in a header file @eozd

Comment: Edit your question to include a [mcve].

Comment: `std::enable_if_t<cond,T>` is `std::enable_if<cond,T>::type`, and template parameters before `::` (`T` here) cannot be deduced.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing your SFINAE on class incorrectly. I will show how to do what you are doing with SFINAE in a minute, but before, I'd like to show that it is way clearer without SFINAE at all, using abridged version:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
struct is_json_allowed : std::integral_constant<bool, 
                     std::is_integral_v<T> || std::is_void_v<T>
                     /* add || operations */> { };
// Use std::bool_constant in C++17 

bool b = is_json_allowed<unsigned int>::value; // true
bool b2 = is_json_allowed<void>::value; // true
bool b3 = is_json_allowed<void*>::value; // false
```

However, just for educational purposes, this is how you do it with SFINAE:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T, class E = void>
struct is_json_allowed : std::false_type {};

template<typename T>
struct is_json_allowed<T, 
                           std::enable_if_t <
                                std::is_same_v<T,unsigned int> ||
                                std::is_same_v<T,bool>
                                /* add more enable_if */ 
                                          >

                      > : std::true_type {};

bool b = is_json_allowed<unsigned int>::value; // true
bool b2 = is_json_allowed<char>::value; // false
```

Comment: how do I add the conditions for `std::is_array` and ensuring the internal type of the array is also `is_json_allowed` without using SFINAE?